# How to remove a sticker from Telegram sticker set (for every user)

Tags: telegram

I created a sticker set by my bot. I added there some junk images. Now I ask myself a question: How to remove a single sticker from Telegram sticker set for every user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use @Stickers Bot, all you need to do is type `/delsticker` and follow the directions from there. As long as you are the owner of the sticker pack, it shouldn't be a problem.

[image]

Comment: What is the user name of this bot?

Comment: the user name is: @Stickers

Answer (score 0):

**Default API connection with URL:**

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot <token>/METHOD_NAME
```

1. In order for your bot to interact with your sticker pack, you must create it using the createNewStickerSet method (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#createnewstickerset )
2. Send the desired sticker to your bot
3. Use the get Updates method (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates).
   In the response, you will get a json structure where you can take the file_id
4. Use deleteStickerFromSet method (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletestickerfromset)

***python example***

```
    def deleteStickerFromSet(file_id: str):
        data = {
            'sticker': file_id,
            }
        r = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot <token>/' + "deleteStickerFromSet", data=data)
```

Returns True on success.